# ressembler vs se voir

Tags: choix-de-mot

Both means "look like" in dictionary, and I'm concerned whether they can be used interchangeably. For example:

> ça **ressemble** à un monstre.
>
> ça **se voit** comme un monstre.

Except the choice between *à / comme*, is there anything else different?

Answer (score 4):

"Ça ressemble à" means strictly "it looks like"; it can never be used for "ça se voit (à/comme)" and vice-versa.

"Ça se voit comme" is often used in the familiar way of saying that something is obvious and that sentence is

"Ça se voit comme un nez au milieu de la figure.".

It means that whatever you are talking about is obvious: it is as easy to detect as is a nose in a face.

You can use "Ça se voit." in a reply to a statement that says something that is easily verifiable.

— Il a un abcès à une de ses molaires à gauche. *He's got an abcess on one of his molars on the left side.*
— Ça se voit, sa joue est enflée.   *I can see that, his chick is swollen.*

"Ça se voit à…" is much more currently used; it's a means to introduce a particularity that shows that something is true;

— Ce chat est malade.
— Comment sait-tu ça ?
— Ça se voit à son nez, parce qu'il est sec¹.
*You see that by the feel of its nose: it is dry.*

¹<sub>*This often mentioned principle is believed to be false by certain people; a cat can have a dry and warm nose and still be healthy, they say.*</sub>

Comment: « Il a un abcès à une de ses molaires à gauche » could be wrote; Il a une plaie dans la bouche a une molaire gauche, **ca ressemble** a un abces.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Medically, a dental abcess is not a wound (plaie), in other words not an external lesion; it is an internal lesion. In all types of English only "written" is standard; what's that type of English you are using? Yes you are right, there is also a case for the use of "ça ressemble" in this context.

Comment: Ok, « Il a la joue gauche enflee, ca ressemble a un abces a une molaire » :)

Answer (score 3):

"Ça ressemble à un monstre" is a correct translation of "it looks like a monster".

"Ça se voit comme un monstre" is not a correct sentence, "ça se voit" means "it is visible / obvious".

I can't see any use for "ça se voit comme", except in the colloquial phrase "ça se voit comme le nez au milieu de la figure" already mentioned in another answer. You could conceivably invent similar sentences like this: "ça se voit comme un éléphant dans la pièce", but any other use of "ça se voit comme" is incorrect.